# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'duration')

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting this error **Cannot read properties of null (reading 'duration')** when I'm trying to do the following
If I render the following function, code works fine

```
renderGrabbers = () => this.state.timings.map((x, index) => (
      <div key={`grabber_${index}`}>
        {console.log(this.state.timings)}
        <div
          className="grabber start"
          style={{ left: `${x.start / this.playVideo.current.duration * 100}%` }}
          onMouseDown={(event) => {
            console.log(event); // eslint-disable-line
            if (this.state.deletingGrabber) {
              this.deleteGrabber(index);
            } else {
              this.setState({ currently_grabbed: { index, type: 'start' } }, () => {
                window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.startGrabberMove);
              });
            }
          }}
        >
          <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="14" viewBox="0 0 10 14" xmlSpace="preserve">
            <path className="st0" d="M1 14L1 14c-0.6 0-1-0.4-1-1V1c0-0.6 0.4-1 1-1h0c0.6 0 1 0.4 1 1v12C2 13.6 1.6 14 1 14zM5 14L5 14c-0.6 0-1-0.4-1-1V1c0-0.6 0.4-1 1-1h0c0.6 0 1 0.4 1 1v12C6 13.6 5.6 14 5 14zM9 14L9 14c-0.6 0-1-0.4-1-1V1c0-0.6 0.4-1 1-1h0c0.6 0 1 0.4 1 1v12C10 13.6 9.6 14 9 14z" />
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div
          className="grabber end"
          style={{ left: `${x.end / this.playVideo.current.duration * 100}%` }}
          onMouseDown={(event) => {
            console.log(event); // eslint-disable-line
            if (this.state.deletingGrabber) {
              this.deleteGrabber(index);
            } else {
              this.setState({ currently_grabbed: { index, type: 'end' } }, () => {
                window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.startGrabberMove);
              });
            }
          }}
        >
          <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="14" viewBox="0 0 10 14" xmlSpace="preserve">
            <path
              className="st0"
              d="M1 14L1 14c-0.6 0-1-0.4-1-1V1c0-0.6 0.4-1 1-1h0c0.6 0 1 0.4 1 1v12C2 13.6 1.6 14 1 14zM5 14L5 14c-0.6 0-1-0.4-1-1V1c0-0.6 0.4-1 1-1h0c0.6 0 1 0.4 1 1v12C6 13.6 5.6 14 5 14zM9 14L9 14c-0.6 0-1-0.4-1-1V1c0-0.6 0.4-1 1-1h0c0.6 0 1 0.4 1 1v12C10 13.6 9.6 14 9 14z"
            />
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    ))
```

**NOTE: timings is an array of dictionaries with keys as 'start' and 'end'**

But now when I am rendering an almost similar function with a small change that the array being mapped is as follows
`clipArray: [{ start_time: 1.248, end_time: 3.254 }, { start_time: 6.711, end_time: 9.282 }]`

The other function is as follows

```
renderGrabbersOnInput = () => this.state.clipArray.map((x, index) => (
      <div key={`grabber_${index}`}>
        <div
          className="grabber start"
          style={{ left: `${x.start_time / this.playVideo.current.duration * 100}%` }}
          onMouseDown={(event) => {
            console.log(event); // eslint-disable-line
            if (this.state.deletingGrabber) {
              this.deleteGrabber(index);
            } else {
              this.setState({ currently_grabbed: { index, type: 'start' } }, () => {
                window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.startGrabberMove);
              });
            }
          }}
        >
          <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="14" viewBox="0 0 10 14" xmlSpace="preserve">
            <path className="st0" d="M1 14L1 14c-0.6 0-1-0.4-1-1V1c0-0.6 0.4-1 1-1h0c0.6 0 1 0.4 1 1v12C2 13.6 1.6 14 1 14zM5 14L5 14c-0.6 0-1-0.4-1-1V1c0-0.6 0.4-1 1-1h0c0.6 0 1 0.4 1 1v12C6 13.6 5.6 14 5 14zM9 14L9 14c-0.6 0-1-0.4-1-1V1c0-0.6 0.4-1 1-1h0c0.6 0 1 0.4 1 1v12C10 13.6 9.6 14 9 14z" />
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div
          className="grabber end"
          style={{ left: `${x.end_time / this.playVideo.current.duration * 100}%` }}
          onMouseDown={(event) => {
            console.log(event); // eslint-disable-line
            if (this.state.deletingGrabber) {
              this.deleteGrabber(index);
            } else {
              this.setState({ currently_grabbed: { index, type: 'end' } }, () => {
                window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.startGrabberMove);
              });
            }
          }}
        >
          <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="14" viewBox="0 0 10 14" xmlSpace="preserve">
            <path
              className="st0"
              d="M1 14L1 14c-0.6 0-1-0.4-1-1V1c0-0.6 0.4-1 1-1h0c0.6 0 1 0.4 1 1v12C2 13.6 1.6 14 1 14zM5 14L5 14c-0.6 0-1-0.4-1-1V1c0-0.6 0.4-1 1-1h0c0.6 0 1 0.4 1 1v12C6 13.6 5.6 14 5 14zM9 14L9 14c-0.6 0-1-0.4-1-1V1c0-0.6 0.4-1 1-1h0c0.6 0 1 0.4 1 1v12C10 13.6 9.6 14 9 14z"
            />
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    ))
```

When I render this I'm getting the said error, can someone help me as to why this is happening.

**this.playVideo is a React ref**

Answer (score 0):

With react useRef, the first time the component renders it’ll be equal to null. It gets a value assigned only once that element with the ref gets mounted.

To go around it, you may want to either wrap your render function with a condition, something like `this.playVideo.current ? <your-render-content> : null`, or add the optional chaining operator where you use it, like: `this.playVideo.current?.duration`

Comment: I hear you but why does it not give a problem for renderGrabbers but gives a problem for renderGrabbersOnInput when actually the whole code is same only different arrays are mapped.

Comment: Depends on where those render function are invoked in; Can't answer that with the information provided above